# properly handling shell escaping from Python using os.system

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sorting, command-line

I'm having trouble properly escaping calls to the shell from within Python, using the os.system command.  I'm trying to do the equivalent of:

```
$ cat test | sort --stable -t $'\t' -k1,1
```

from within Python, passing that to the shell.

I tried:

```
import os
cmd = "cat %s | sort --stable -t $'\\t' -k1,1" %("test")
os.system(cmd)
```

but I get the error:

```
sort: multi-character tab `$\\t'
```

although it works correctly from the shell.  I tried to escape the `\t` by adding an extra slash in Python, but I must be missing something else. Any idea how this can be fixed?

thanks.

Comment: you can pass the filename as an arg to sort, and skip the `cat file |`. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`os.system` doesn't execute commands in a normal bash environment like you would expect.  You can work around it by simply calling bash yourself:

```py
import os
cmd = """/bin/bash -c "cat %s | sort --stable -t $'\t' -k1,1" """ % "test"
os.system(cmd)
```

But you should be aware that `os.system` has been marked as deprecated, and will be removed in future versions of python.  You can future-proof your code by using `subprocess`'s convenience method `call` that mimics `os.system`'s behavior:

```
import subprocess
cmd = """/bin/bash -c "cat %s | sort --stable -t $'\t' -k1,1" """ % "test"
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

There are more ways to make that call with the subprocess module if you are interested:

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

Answer (score 1):

First, you should avoid useless-use-of-cat: http://google.com/search?q=uuoc.

Secondly, are you sure that your sort command not understand backslash-t?  This should work:

```
sort --stable -t'\t' -k1,1 test
```

It should also work just fine from Python:

```
os.system("sort --stable -t'\\t' -k1,1 test")
# or
os.system(r"sort --stable -t'\t' -k1,1 test")
```

Finally, if you switch to `subprocess` (recommended), avoid using `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.call(["sort", "--stable", "-t\t", "-k1,1", "test"])
```